# Css3 hyperlinks hover over effect using jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i'm trying to make a link like [this](http://useyourinterface.com/post/84822354246). so far i use jquery, you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajibari/8A6Ax/). 
Problem comes when you hover the link. it's covered by the purple container.
I've added `z-index` for both of them but still not work as expected. Also sometimes the purple container is getting far to the right.
I don't have idea what keyword should i use for google. I really need some help. I don't mind if there's solution with CSS only.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/8A6Ax/7/

Comment: lol they are all right. you should be able to get this working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO HERE (GOT IT UPDATED)**](http://jsfiddle.net/8A6Ax/10/)

[**DEMO HERE (GOT IT UPDATED 2)**](http://jsfiddle.net/8A6Ax/13/)

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.placeholder{
    background: grey;
    height: 60px;
    width: 140px;
    position:relative;
}
#kotak{
    position: absolute;
    left:-140px;
    top:0;
    width: 140px;
    height: 60px;
    background: purple;
    z-index:1;
}
a{
    z-index:10;
    color: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
```

see the updated fiddle. the one is fixed

Comment: thanks, it works. but when i hovering faster, sometimes i can't see the purple container. how do i solve this? should i added duration or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index` property only works on elements whose position is not static (i.e. you must have given them a position value of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`. I've updated your fiddle accordingly to fix this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8A6Ax/11/)**

```
.placeholder{
    background: grey;
    height: 60px;
    width: 140px;
    overflow: hidden; // prevent #kotak from running outside of your button
}
#kotak{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 60px;
    background: purple;
}
a{
    position: relative;  // allows z-index to work properly
    z-index:1;
    color: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert below code to your `.placeholder` css class

```
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
```

also you should stop animation before start the new one

Answer (score 0):

need to add position to the css for the link or the z-index wont apply. 
the position relative without other options defined has no real impact on the layout so its likely the best option here

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.placeholder{
    position: relative;
    background: grey;
    height: 60px;
    width: 140px;
}
#kotak{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 0;
    height: 60px;
    background: purple;
    z-index:1;
}
a{
    z-index:10;
    color: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```